# Clear data when a sheet is unprotected

Tags: vba, password-protection

I have an excel file with a sheet that is protected by password. If somebody is able to hack the password or somehow able to unprotect that sheet, I want all the data in there to be deleted automatically. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jaja, you should be aware that people that can hack the password probably knows how to circumvent the macro that's deleting the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, and it could delete an unprotected sheet

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Protected"
     Else
        MsgBox "Not protected"
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
     End If
End Sub
```

Put it on thisworkbook module, and it should be working just fine.
I'm using office 2016 on windows 10

Comment: This will not work if there is only one sheet in the workbook as a workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet. If there is only one sheet consider using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents` instead.

Comment: Thank you Tom & Elrond. Much appreciated!